# Python - VRPTW, appending results to a df

Tags: python, pandas, vehicle-routing

I have implemented a VRP algorithm that generates a route using the nearest neighbor algorithm and improves the route using the 2-opt algorithm. The resulting code calculates the distance of a given route and returns the improved route and distance.

Now, I want to create a Pandas DataFrame from the resulting code, where the columns are node, group, order, distance, cumulative distance. I am struggling to create the DataFrame, so I am looking for some guidance on how to achieve this.

Here is the code that generates the route and the improved route:

```py
# Define the number of vehicles
num_vehicles = 3

# Define the depot location (distribution center)
depot = 0

# Define the current node (starting node)
current_node = 0

def nearest_neighbor(d_matrix, start, max_distance, return_to_depot=True):
    # Initialize the route and visited nodes
    route = [start]
    visited = {start}
    current_node = start
    total_distance = 0
    already_visited = set()

    # Visit the nearest unvisited neighbor until the maximum distance is reached
    while total_distance < max_distance:
        # Find the nearest unvisited neighbor
        unvisited_neighbors = d_matrix[current_node]
        if return_to_depot:
            unvisited_neighbors = unvisited_neighbors[~unvisited_neighbors.index.isin(visited)]
        if unvisited_neighbors.empty:
            break
        nearest_neighbor = unvisited_neighbors[~unvisited_neighbors.index.isin(already_visited)].idxmin()

        # Check if visiting the nearest neighbor and returning to the depot will exceed the maximum distance
        if return_to_depot and total_distance + d_matrix[current_node][nearest_neighbor] + \
                d_matrix[nearest_neighbor][depot] > max_distance:
            break

        # Visit the nearest unvisited neighbor
        visited.add(nearest_neighbor)
        already_visited.add(nearest_neighbor)
        route.append(nearest_neighbor)
        total_distance += d_matrix[current_node][nearest_neighbor]
        current_node = nearest_neighbor

    return route, total_distance

# Implement a simple 2-opt algorithm to improve the solution
def two_opt(route, dist_matrix):
    # Initialize the best route and distance
    best_route = route
    best_distance = calculate_distance(best_route, dist_matrix)

    # Perform 2-opt optimization until no improvement can be made
    improvement = True
    while improvement:
        improvement = False
        for i in range(1, len(route) - 1):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(route)):
                new_route = route[:i] + route[i:j][::-1] + route[j:]
                new_distance = calculate_distance(new_route, dist_matrix)
                if new_distance < best_distance:
                    best_route = new_route
                    best_distance = new_distance
                    improvement = True
        route = best_route

    return best_route, best_distance

# Calculate the distance of a given route
def calculate_distance(route, d_matrix):
    distance = 0
    for i in range(len(route) - 1):
        distance += d_matrix[route[i]][route[i + 1]]
    return distance

# Generate a route using the nearest neighbor algorithm
route, total_distance = nearest_neighbor(d_matrix, depot, max_distance, set())

# Improve the route using the 2-opt algorithm
improved_route, improved_distance = two_opt(route, d_matrix)
```

Can someone please help me create the Pandas DataFrame I described earlier? Thank you in advance! :)

Example output (Maybe even a running total column):

| Node. | Group | Order | Distance | Cummulative_Distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 6 | 10 |
| 6 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 12 |
| 0 | 1 | 5 | 10 | 22 |
| 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 5 |
| 0 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 8 |
| 0 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 | 6 | 6 |
| 7 | 3 | 3 | 13 | 13 |
| 0 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 17 |